# Fetch a row via ODBC when there are 2 SQL statements: insert and select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, odbc

I can't fetch a row in a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO ...;
SELECT ...;
```

The query in correct and the INSERT statement succeed, but SQLFetch returns false.

If I remove the INSERT statement and leave only the SELECT, SQLFetch returns true and everything is OK.

I use SQLExecDirect to execute a query and SQLFetch to fetch.

Comment: Try including `SET NOCOUNT ON` before the `INSERT`.

Comment: Yep. You read my mind. I've come to this solution too. But anyway thanks. :)